# Can't open Images with Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a Game in Python using the Pygame module, and I'm getting this error:

```
pygame.error: Couldn't open C:\Users\16052\Desktop\Pygame folder\Pygame-Images.zip\Game\bg.jpg
```

So PyGame couldn't open my Images

This is the Code for my Images:

```
# the Images for the game

walkingRight = [
            pygame.image.load('C:\Users\16052\Desktop\Pygame folder\Pygame-Images.zip\Game\bg.jpg'),
            pygame.image.load('C:\Users\16052\Desktop\Pygame folder\Pygame-Images.zip\Game\R3.png'),
            pygame.image.load('C:\Users\16052\Desktop\Pygame folder\Pygame-Images.zip\Game\R4.png'),
            pygame.image.load('C:\Users\16052\Desktop\Pygame folder\Pygame-Images.zip\Game\R5.png'),
            pygame.image.load('C:\Users\16052\Desktop\Pygame folder\Pygame-Images.zip\Game\R6.png'),
            pygame.image.load('C:\Users\16052\Desktop\Pygame folder\Pygame-Images.zip\Game\R7.png'),
            pygame.image.load('C:\Users\16052\Desktop\Pygame folder\Pygame-Images.zip\Game\R8.png'),
            pygame.image.load('C:\Users\16052\Desktop\Pygame folder\Pygame-Images.zip\Game\R9.png')

]

walkingLeft = [
            pygame.image.load('C:\Users\16052\Desktop\Pygame folder\Pygame-Images.zip\Game\L1.png'),
            pygame.image.load('C:\Users\16052\Desktop\Pygame folder\Pygame-Images.zip\Game\L2.png'),
            pygame.image.load('C:\Users\16052\Desktop\Pygame folder\Pygame-Images.zip\Game\L3.png'),
            pygame.image.load('C:\Users\16052\Desktop\Pygame folder\Pygame-Images.zip\Game\L4.png'),
            pygame.image.load('C:\Users\16052\Desktop\Pygame folder\Pygame-Images.zip\Game\L5.png'),
            pygame.image.load('C:\Users\16052\Desktop\Pygame folder\Pygame-Images.zip\Game\L6.png'),
            pygame.image.load('C:\Users\16052\Desktop\Pygame folder\Pygame-Images.zip\Game\L7.png'),
            pygame.image.load('C:\Users\16052\Desktop\Pygame folder\Pygame-Images.zip\Game\L8.png'),
            pygame.image.load('C:\Users\16052\Desktop\Pygame folder\Pygame-Images.zip\Game\L9.png')

]
```

The error is where I define the `walkingLeft` and `walkingRight` variables.
I've been trying to fix this bug for hours, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Personally I find the easiest thing to do is to put the images in the same file as the interpreter. The program will then accept the simpler option pygame.image.load('L1.png')

Comment: That should be giving another error because you don't have r before the image path. `pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\16052\Desktop\Pygame folder\Pygame-Images.zip\Game\L1.png')`

Comment: Oh ok I'll try it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the folder before doing anything. This doesnt work in zip files

Hoped this helped

Comment: Thanks, I'll Extract the file

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the Pygame-Images folder.

You can change `'C:\Users\16052\Desktop\Pygame folder\Pygame-Images\Game\L1.png'` by the absolute path (for example if your `.py` file is in the `Pygame folder` folder, change by `\Pygame-Images\Game\L1.png`.

Change all the `\` by `\\` or add a `r` before the first `'` of each image path

You can simplify the code with a list comprehension like that:

```
path = '\\Pygame-Images\\Game\\'
images = ['L1.png', 'L2.png', 'L3.png', ...]
images = [pygame.image.load(path+image) for image in images]
```